# How do I integrate clover current db file and history files , and get the coverage result together?

Tags: web-services, end-to-end, clover, test-coverage

In my case, I have to get code coverage  in server.For that I use clover. I have executed  test cases for some scenarios  through client side manually That means logging to the web application and manually test some scenarios ). Then I want to get result as what are the test coverage during testing. While I test, there may be situations like application build again. That means I lost my coverage data file. After testing finish, then it shows only coverage which is covered after new app build. Clover provides history point option which save .xml.gz file on the history directory. I want to know How I integrate this history file and currently updated clove.db file and  create a report which cover all of my testing ?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but: if the application is built again then you don't know what actually was changed (it can be completely different code), therefore all your manual tests done so far are invalid.

I would rather suggest to stop deploying new version of your application during manual testing.

Alternatively, in case you control when new version is deployed, you could gather clover.db and coverage recording files collected so far and generate intermediate reports - to see at least coverage for some of the tests.